# selenium cannot find button after pressing on next page

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, python-3.9

I want to read all results from the table in this website: https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/results
[image]

at the end of the page there is a next button to press to move to next page

This is my code: which reads the table then goes to the press the next button.

```
stocks = []
count = 1

while(count <= pages):
    print("pages: {}".format(pages))
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
    time.sleep(3)
    
    table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table"))
        )

    rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    for row in rows:
        # Get the columns (all the column 2)        
        col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
        if len(col) != 0:
            s = (col[0].text)
            sep = '\n'
            stripped = s.split(sep, 1)[0]
            if len(stocks) == 0:
                stocks.append(stripped)
            else:
                if stocks[-1] != stripped:
                    stocks.append(stripped)
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/section/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[8]"))
        )
        
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1200)")

    element.click()

    print(stocks)
    count+=1
```

I am facing a problem when after reading the first page and clicking on next, selenium is unable find the next button in the second page anymore. I have tried using CSS Selectors and XPath copied from the webpage itself. Still unable to find the button element.

For more reference, here is the error code :
[image]

If Do not use the webdriver wait function:

```
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1200)")
    time.sleep(3)
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/section/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[8]")
```

which cause this error:
[image]

:0 :( sad

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below xpath for next button click.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='More results']/.."))
    )
element.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just want to check if the button is out of view, will this still work?

Comment: Yes it will work. If it is facing issue then you can always try scroll to element using java script exexutor. It is reliable solution.WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);